# How to Show only the posts and comments from people I follow?

Tags: chatter, connect-api

I want to replicate people filter logic in apex which shows only the posts and comments from people I follow. Is there any connectApi Namespaces availabe for this? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for the above question:

Use below method with `FeedType = ConnectApi.FeedType.People`

```
getFeedItemsFromFeed(String, ConnectApi.FeedType, String, Integer, ConnectApi.FeedDensity, String, Integer, ConnectApi.FeedSortOrder, Boolean)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to retrieve this information from one of the methods in the ChatterFeeds class.

Have a read of this help topic in the Apex Code Developer guide on working with feeds in Apex: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/intro_feeds_feed_items.htm